# derivative of cross product of vectors with respect to vector

Tags: vectors, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, cross-product

I am working on deriving equations for mechanics problem including vector calculus, more specifically, derivatives of cross product of vectors with respect to a vector.

Let $\boldsymbol{a},\boldsymbol{b}$ be vectors.
Then, I know that

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{a}}\left(\boldsymbol{a} \times \boldsymbol{b}\right) = -\left[\boldsymbol{B}\right],\quad \frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{b}}\left(\boldsymbol{a} \times \boldsymbol{b}\right) = \left[\boldsymbol{A}\right],\qquad$where $\left[\boldsymbol{A}\right] = skew \left(\boldsymbol{a}\right), \quad \left[\boldsymbol{B}\right] = skew \left(\boldsymbol{b}\right)$.

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{a}} \left|\left|\boldsymbol{a}\right|\right| = \frac{\boldsymbol{a}}{\left|\left|\boldsymbol{a}\right|\right|}$

Based on this, 
I have been struggling with how to take the derivative of the following vector product

$ \left(1\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{a}}\left\lbrace\boldsymbol{a} \times \left(  \boldsymbol{a} \times \boldsymbol{b}\right)\right\rbrace $

$ \left(2\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{a}}\left\lbrace\boldsymbol{b} \times \left(  \boldsymbol{b} \times \boldsymbol{a}\right)\right\rbrace $

$ \left(3\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{a}}\left[ \left|\left|  \boldsymbol{a} \right|\right| \left\lbrace   \boldsymbol{b} \times \left(  \boldsymbol{b} \times \boldsymbol{a}\right)\right\rbrace \right] $

Anyone who has experience of those problems, could you help me, please? And also, it would be deeply appreciated if you could show me any references such as book or website I can refer to.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, Geoffrey.
$a \times a=b\times b=0$, but $a \times \left(a \times b\right) \neq 0$.
For example, let $a=\left\lbrace1,2,3\right\rbrace, b=\left\lbrace4,5,6\right\rbrace$. Then $a \times \left(a \times b \right) = \left\lbrace-24,-6,12\right\rbrace$.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I wasn't thinking. I'll delete that comment.

Comment: Thank you, though!

Answer (score 1):

Use the "BAC-CAB" rule:
$$ a\times(b\times c) = b(a^Tc) - c(a^Tb) $$
to expand the cross products before taking derivatives.

For example, here is a solution for case (1).

Find the differential and then the gradient.

$$\eqalign{
y &= a\times(a\times b) \cr
  &= (b^Ta)a - (a^Ta)b \cr
dy &= (b^Ta)\,da + (b^Tda)a - 2(a^Tda)b \cr
   &= \Big((b^Ta)I + ab^T - 2ba^T\Big)\,da \cr
\frac{\partial y}{\partial a} &= (b^Ta)I + ab^T - 2ba^T \cr
}$$
Note that I've used matrix notation for the dot products, i.e. $\,\,a^Tb=a\cdot b$

The solution to case (3) can be put in an intriguing form
$$\|a\|^{-1}\big(bb^T-b^TbI\big)\big(aa^T + a^TaI\big)$$

Comment: Thank you greg, I deeply appreciate your answer and help..

Comment: Hello greg! Your answer was great and very helpful to me. I have a question about the solution to the case (3) you've given.

For example, if we have the following simple problem,

$\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \left( \Arrowvert a \Arrowvert a \right)$.

for this problem, what I did was..

$\\\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \left( \Arrowvert a \Arrowvert a \right)= \frac{\partial \Arrowvert a \Arrowvert}{\partial a}a^{T} + \Arrowvert a \Arrowvert I =\frac{1}{\Arrowvert a \Arrowvert}\left(a a^T + a^TaI \right) $. Is that exactly what you used to derive the solution to case(3)?